# How to check is two lines intersect/overlap on a grid?

Tags: objective-c

This is a rather trivial algorithmic problem but my implementation leaves speed and simplicity to be desired. I've got two Line objects which each hold two Coordinate structs in the form of `{unsigned int x, unsigned int y}`. This first Coordinate holds the position of the beginning of the line and the second Coordinate, the end of it. Assuming that Lines can only be vertical or horizontal on the grid, how can I check when two lines overlap parallelly or intersect perpendicularly. Preferably this is implemented as a method in Line:

```
- (BOOL)intersectsLine:(Line)otherLine;
```

THANKS!

Comment: Is this an algebra question, or do you know the maths and are having trouble translating it to Objective-C?  (And why are the coordinates unsigned...?)

Comment: Well I implemented it non-mathematically and I'm not well versed enough in math to make my method any better.

Comment: The coordinates are unsigned because my grid need only be in the first quadrant. The top-left corner of the grid is {0, 0} in my program.

Comment: How could you possibly implement this non-mathematically?  And either way, if you're looking for improvement of your algorithm, I suggest posting it here so we can look at it.  I'd also recommend checking some of the math stack exchange sites where some real math-heads can really tell you the best way to solve the problem (and then you can translate it into code).

Comment: I populated an array for each line which represents all the grid coordinates contained within that line. Then I did the same for the line to be compared to. Then I iterate through both arrays to find a common coordinate.

Comment: Well that's certainly inefficient... nonetheless, the code for this implementation should be included in the question.

Comment: Well seeing as my solution is really inefficient, I don't see why it's necessary. You'd have to start the method from scratch to make it any more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we're talking only about horizontal or vertical lines, the first step I'd take it checking whether or not the lines have the same orientation.

```
typedef (NSUInteger, LineOrientation) {
    HorizontalLine = 0,
    VerticalLine = 1
};
```

So, given a line with two points...

```
LineOrientation line1orientation;
LineOrientation line2orientation;    

if (a.x1 == a.x2) {
    line1orientation = HorizontalLine;
} else {
    line1orientation = VerticalLine;
}

if (b.x1 == b.x2) {
    line2orientation = VerticalLine;
} else {
    line2orientation = Horizontal;
}
```

Now we need to check whether they're both horizontal, both vertical, or one of each, and then test particular values:

```
if (line1orientation == line2orientation) {
    if (line1orientation == VerticalLine) {
        if (a.x1 != b.x1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (a.y1 < a.y2) {
                return ((b.y1 > a.y1 && b.y1 < a.y2) || 
                    (b.y2 > a.y1 && b.y2 < a.y2));
            } else {
                return ((b.y1 > a.y2 && b.y1 < a.y1) ||
                    (b.y2 > a.y2 && b.y2 < a.y1));
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (a.y1 != b.y1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            if (a.x1 < a.x2) {
                return ((b.x1 > a.x1 && b.x1 < a.x2) ||
                    (b.x2 > a.x1 && b.x2 < a.x2));
            } else {
                return ((b.x1 > a.x2 && b.x1 < a.x1) ||
                    (b.x2 > a.x2 && b.x2 < a.x1));
            }
        }
    }
} else {
    if (line1orientation == VerticalLine) {
        if (a.y1 < a.y2) {
            return (((b.y1 > a.y1) && (b.y1 < a.y2)) && ((b.x1 > a.x1 && b.x2 
                < a.x1) || (b.x2 > a.x1 && b.x1 < a.x1)));
        } else {
            return (((b.y1 > a.y2) && (b.y1 < a.y1)) && ((b.x1 > a.x1 && b.x2 
                < a.x1) || (b.x2 > a.x1 && b.x1 < a.x1)))
        }
    } else {
        if (a.x1 < a.x2) {
            return (((b.x1 > a.x1) && (b.x1 < a.x2)) && ((b.y1 > a.y1 && b.y2 
                < a.y2) || (b.y2 > a.y1 && b.y1 < a.y1)));
        } else {
            return (((b.x1 > a.x2) && (b.x1 < a.x1)) && ((b.y1 > a.y1 && b.y2 
                < a.y2) || (b.y2 > a.y1 && b.y1 < a.y1)));
    }
}
```

This could be more efficient if you start with a check to make sure the lines aren't the same line.

Comment: I think this is right... it looks complicated, but should actually run fairly fast, particularly compared to checking several points in an array.